# how to change the task status into failed in hadoop mapreduce on exception

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, mapreduce

Im using hadoop mapreduce for the following task:

My mapper will read the `.xml` file from HDFS and pass it to some service. I 'm having some code like this in my `setup()`:

```
try
{
    System.out.println(propertyName);
    session = FindPath.createSession("localhost",3250, EncodingConstants.en_ISO_8859_1);
    session.open();
}
catch 
{
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

When the datanode is not having the `FindPath` [ FindPath - service is not yet started ] it will throw an exception.

Now my problem is my mapper program is not moved to the other cluster which has the runing `FindPath` service.

**Example**:

Datanode 1    Datanode 2 - two data nodes

If DataNode 1 is not yet started the `FindPath` service, then the Input should move to  Datanode 2.

How can I achieve that?

**And how can I change the `TaskStatus` in Datanode 1 to 'Failed'  when it throws an exception?**

**UPDATE**

```
Job j;
catch(Exception Ex)
{   
    j.failTask((TaskAttemptID)context.getTaskAttemptID());
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

I have used something like this but it throws an NullPointer exception.

How to use `failTask` in my **mapper or mapper setup** new API?

Comment: so, you want to fail a map and reprocess the data with a different map in some other node where you have the service available?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker  yes . i want to do so

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker im using new API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `JobClient` to access the `RunningJob` class ( I have 1.0.4 API).

So the code looks like this:

Have a `JobClient` and a `RunningJob`reference in your `setup()`.

The method is as follows:

```
public void setup(Context context)
{
    JobClient jobClient;
    RunningJob runningJob;

    try 
    {
        jobClient = new JobClient((JobConf)context.getConfiguration());
        runningJob = jobClient.getJob((JobID)(context.getJobId()); //mapred.JobID!
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }


    try
    {
        System.out.println(propertyName);
        session = FindPath.createSession("localhost",3250, EncodingConstants.en_ISO_8859_1);
        session.open();
    }
    catch 
    {
        System.out.println("error");
        runningJob.killTask((TaskAttemptID)context.getTaskAttemptID(), true);// cast as mapred.TaskAttemptID
    }

}
```

This causes the TaskAttempt to fail.

Finally, you should probably set `mapred.map.max.attempts` to 1 so that a failed taskAttempt is a failed task.

### Note:

You should consider altering  `mapred.max.map.failures.percent` as it reflects the tolerance of your cluster towards failed tasks.

Comment: Edited because I did't notice that you need to fail the task in `setup` rather than `map`.

Comment: Can you please tell the exact version ( I got confused with the many different APIs :) ) ?

Comment: Im  using Job and mapreduce . V-1.2.

Comment: @Backtrack well, me too but in 1.0.4. But there is still no limitation using a `JobClient` in your Tasks and keep `Job` in your driver. Unless of course I am missing something.

Comment: Okay ... I will post the exception now .. Then it will be useful for you to understand